# Javascript syntax on Facebook developer page

Tags: javascript, facebook

I don't get some of the syntax in this block of code taken from the facebook developers site. 
Are the first variables 'js' and 'id' bound in some way? What exactly is being returned in the first if statement?

```
     (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
```

This is the link to the page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#personalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "bound"?

They're function-local; `js` is a variable set in the 3rd and 4th lines, `id` is set to a string immediately.

The function itself is executed immediately after definition, with `d` set to `document` inside the function.

Nothing is returned by the first (and only explicit) `return` statement. And if this is the only code, a return value would be meaningless, because nothing captures the return value.

Comment: I'm not used to seeing javascript written this way so I thought that var js and id were somehow apart of the same variable since there is only one equal sign after them and they're only separated by a comma and not a semicolon like the other lines.

Comment: @Spilot Nope; commas are used to separate declarations, whether or not there is an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing exiting here, just stolen whitespaces :)

```
(function(d){
    var js,    // variable (empty)
        id = 'facebook-jssdk';    // variable with string 'facebook-jssdk'

    if (d.getElementById(id)) {    // is there an element with id 'facebook-jssdk'
        return;    // yes, so we have nothing to do and get out of here
    }

    js = d.createElement('script');    // create 'script' element
    js.id = id;    // assign id 'facebook-jssdk'
    js.async = true;    // load in "background" (if supported)
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";    // set source (with the appropriate protocol; https if called via https, http otherwise)
    d.getElementByTagNam('head')[0].appendChild(js);    // append to first head element on page
}(document))    // immediately call the anonymous function and hand in the 'document'
```